# Facing Issue While Playing a Video in Linux using VLCJ and JMF

Tags: java, linux, video, vlcj

I want to play a video in frame using Java code in LUbuntu.

Till now I have used JMF and VLCJ framework for playing a video, it works absolutely fine on windows but not on Linux (It gives me FATAL error if I use VLCJ even for the same code which runs on windows and JMF doesn't get install on linux-ubuntu).

I have used 32 bit Linux and 1.8 JDK. Is there compatibility issue with Linux drivers and JMF drivers ?

But now I am trying to run via any script that will enable me playing a video on a frame not on browser.

It will be great if you give me proper guidance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vlcj currently will not work on 32-bit Ubuntu, at least not without some nasty workarounds.

In fact, this will fail even if you do not use vlcj, if you write the code yourself without using vlcj you are guaranteed to see the same failure.

The issue is caused by some combination of Java, VLC, LUA and 32-bit Ubuntu.

Probably the simplest workaround is to delete the VLC LUA scripts, but that will disable some functionality (such as YouTube).

There is a lot of background information here, way too much to reproduce in this answer:

https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/62

Comment: Hello Caprica thanks for the answer. I have already read the link which you have provided. I am asking is there any other way that I can play a video in frame in linux os. I have also tried using JMF but I am unable to install that (.bin) file in the same os. I will be glad if you provide me a way. Thanks.

Comment: Some people use xuggler, but I can only help with vlcj